# SonarQube Scanner Analysis on Changes

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, static-analysis, sonarqube-scan

I'm running the maven sonar goal against feature branch builds as a gating factor for merging into our master branch. This takes quite a while, and all that I'm really concerned with is ensuring that new code meets our standards. Is there a way to just run the scanner against the new changes instead of against the whole project to save on build time?

Comment: Do you happen to be using GitHub or Bitbucket on Demand for SCM?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam I'm using BitBucket Server for SCM.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using BitBucket, then you can [use a plugin](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash) to make SonarQube a commenter on pull requests. It will raise issues on the new code in the pull request. Then as part of your manual review, you can evaluate any new issues.

Comment: Does it really show _new_ issues or all issues in the build? I already used such a plugin for Sonarqube and Bitbucket (not sure if it was the one you've linked) and it only showed all issues in the code, not only the ones introduced in the pull request.

Comment: Yeah, the "new" issues are what I'm really concerned with. Our codebase is over 1.5 million lines of code, and static analysis takes almost an hour to run. Ideally, we'd like to be able to do a couple of things...

1. Run static code analysis ONLY on the diff
2. Run code coverage on everything

I'm not sure if there's a way to specify static analysis inclusions separately from the global inclusions list. If there were, we could use a git diff to get the changed files and narrow down the focus for static analysis to that.

Comment: @Tom it's supposed to show only issues new in the PR as compared to what's already showing up in your SQ instance & that's the behavior I've seen in our internal use.